# How can RegEx named match HTML attributes and ignore order?

Tags: python, regex, wordpress

I currently have the following RegEx workflow to match WordPress caption tags and subsitute them by Jekyll caption tags:

```
import sys, re

def re_sub(pattern, replacement, string):
    def _r(m):
        # Now this is ugly.
        # Python has a "feature" where unmatched groups return None
        # then re.sub chokes on this.
        # see http://bugs.python.org/issue1519638

        # this works around and hooks into the internal of the re module...

        # the match object is replaced with a wrapper that
        # returns "" instead of None for unmatched groups

        class _m():
            def __init__(self, m):
                self.m=m
                self.string=m.string
            def group(self, n):
                return m.group(n) or ""

        return re._expand(pattern, _m(m), replacement)

    return re.sub(pattern, _r, string)

def parseCaptions(content):
    """
    [caption id="attachment_76716" align="aligncenter" width="500"]<a href="http://martin-thoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/WER-calculation.png"><img src="http://martin-thoma.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/WER-calculation.png" alt="WER calculation" width="500" height="494" class="size-full wp-image-76716" /></a> WER calculation[/caption]

    to

    {% caption align="aligncenter" width="500" alt="WER calculation" text="WER calculation" url="../images/2013/11/WER-calculation.png" %}
    """
    import re

    pattern = '\[caption(.*?)align="(?P<align>.*?)"(.*?)caption="(?P<caption>.*?)"(.*?)\]' + \
        '<a(.*?)href=\"(?P<url>(.*?))\"(?P<asonst>.*?)>' + \
        '<img(.*?)src=\"(?P<imgurl>http://martin-thoma.com/wp-content/uploads/(?P<innerurl>(.*?)))\" ' + \
            '(class=\"(?P<imgclass>.*?)\")?\s*' + \
            'title=\"(?P<title>.*?)\"\s*' + \
            '(alt=\"(?P<alt>.*?)\")?\s*' + \
            'width=\"(?P<width>.*?)\"\s*' + \
            'height=\"(?P<height>.*?)\"\s*' + \
            '(?P<isonst>.*?)/>' + \
        '</a>\s*' + \
        '(?P<text>.*?)\[/caption\]'
    pattern = re.compile(pattern)
    results = [m.groupdict() for m in pattern.finditer(content)]
    for result in results:
        for key, value in result.items():
            print("%s:\t%s" % (key, value))

    content = re_sub(pattern, '{% caption align="\g<align>" width="\g<width>" caption="\g<caption>\g<text>" url="../images/\g<innerurl>" alt="\g<alt>" title="\g<title>" height="\g<height>" class="\g<imgclass>" %}', content)

    return content
```

My regex is not very good, because the order of attributes inside a tag does not matter in reallity, but it matters for my regex. How can I make the regex match any order within a tag (but at most once or match the latest occurence)?

(edit: another reason why this RegEx is suboptimal is that all groups should replace `"` by `'`)

Comment: I think that would be much better to not use Regexp for this. Use some XML parser instead.

Comment: I don't think that WordPress articles are valid XML. And I guess XML parsers will have problems with invalid XML.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WordPress, but probably regexp are still the "wrong" way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Faust: Why do you think so? Do you know a better solution?

Comment: Because, also if that is not valid XML, it looks pretty much as an XML-like dialect. And, when dealing with regexp, you'll have all the issues that you have with standard XML. Which are exactly the problems that you have here. I'll go with something "simple" like find and replace.